# JavaScript - Creating elements with innerHTML duplicates them. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

When creating elements in JavaScript with innerHTML, it duplicates the tags.

```
let container = document.querySelector(".container");

// This creates two Paragraphs
container.innerHTML = "<p> Paragraph <\p>";

// This only creates one Header 3
container.innerHTML += "<h3> Header 3";

// This doesn't close <strong> correctly and creates two Header 2
container.innerHTML += "<h2><strong> Strong Header<\strong> Not Strong header <\h2> ";
```

Here's a good viewable Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hdvxtujn/10/

I've figured out, that if i only use an open tag, the element closes itself without duplication.
However, If i close the tag, the element duplicates itself with an empty element.

How come so and how to escape this? I would also like to add `<strong>` tag as displayed in the last example.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem was caused by a typo. End tags start with a `/` not a ```\```

Answer (score 4):

It's duplicating them, because you don't close the tags correctly. You use the backslash `\` in your closing tags instead of the slash `/`. Also, your `h3` closing tag is almost completely missing.

Check out this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdvxtujn/11/).

**Snippet:**

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");

container.innerHTML = "<p> Paragraph </p>";
container.innerHTML += "<h3> Header </h3>";
container.innerHTML += "<h2><strong> Strong Header</strong> Not Strong header </h2> ";
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white
}

h2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white
}

h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color:green;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to close the tag with backslashes, when you should be closing them with forward slashes.

Try this one:

```
let container = document.querySelector(".container");

// This creates two Paragraphs
container.innerHTML = "<p> Paragraph </p>";

// This only creates one Header 3
container.innerHTML += "<h3> Header 3";

// This doesn't close <strong> correctly and creates two Header 2
container.innerHTML += "<h2><strong> Strong Header</strong> Not Strong header </h2> ";
```